# id not attaching to custom control

Tags: c#, asp.net, custom-controls

Hey so I am having a problem attaching an id to a custom control. I'll state what I've tried first and if there's anyone out there that can shed some light on why my element isn't appearing on the dom with an id attached that would be awesome.

I've added the inheritance

```
public class BarButton : Control
```

I've attached to button.(100% the right button)

```
  <cc2:BarButton ID="btnDeleteRow" ButtonType="DeleteRow"></cc2:BarButton>
```

Attached in designer

```
protected global::SCNControls.BarButton btnDeleteRow;
```

Anyways after this I have a function to delete the button based on it's id using jQuery. The problem occurs now as when I load the page the button has no ID.

```
   var btnDeleteRow = <%= btnDeleteRow.ClientID%>;
```

^^^^This returns a null value.

Anyways a little light if at all possible would be greatly appreciated. I've checked my elements on the page to see what is being rendered and it's a normal BarButton but with no ID attached. Thanks again.

Comment: Try to modify your javascript code with var btnDeleteRow = document.getElementById('<%= btnDeleteRow.ClientID%>');

Comment: Still getting null....... It's really bugging me now cause I thought this would be a simple bug to fix...

Comment: Try creating your button dynamically. Are you still unable to reference by ID?

Comment: Where is placed this piece of code? Is attached on a js load page event?

Comment: No luck on loading dynamically. It's in a javascript script that's loaded on the page. There's other functions in it that find elements by ID that work fine.